# free PHP/MySQL server with FTP,cPanel and no ads

Tags: web-server, linux

i am looking for a free hosting provider (domain space) from where i can get **PHP/MySQL with atleast 25MB storage and atleast 1GB bandwidth** !
The server should be fast while serving pages !
There should not be any forced ad or banner !
from where can i have it ?
It would be better if i got a cPanel !
any idea ?
i tried x10host and 00host both are damn slow :x :(

Comment: [T.A.N.S.T.A.A.F.L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)

Comment: @Iain Hey look, i flagged your comment as GREAT :)

Answer (score 5):

Sir, *you get what you pay for*. This isn't a free world. You have to earn things. You can't expect people to give you fast servers if they can't make any money off of you. Many products are free for you to use because they make money off of advertising space. Some things have limited free options because they expect you to upgrade to some payed plan when they see how good their service is.

But please, **Server Fault is about answering questions from people administering systems**, not helping users find system administrators to abuse by using their stuff for free.